# Sum of probability density functions - can I treat this as a geometric series?

Tags: probability, random-variable, density-function

I have a random variable, $S_i$, that arises as the infinite weighted sum of another random variable $X_i$ in the form:

\begin{equation}
S_i = aX_i + a^2 X_{i-1} + a^3 X_{i-2} \ldots a^{n-1}X_{i-n+1}
\end{equation}

I would like to find the probability density function of $S$, $g\left(S\right)$, in terms of the probability density function of $X$, $g\left(X\right)$, and the parameter $a$. I am able to do this numerically, but it would be helpful if this were possible as an analytic solution.

I know that $g\left(S\right)$ is the convolution of all the terms on the right hand side, and I know that each of the values of $X_j$ are independent, so can I simplify this to be something like:

\begin{equation}
g\left(S\right) = g\left(X\right)\left(a + a^2 + a^3 \ldots a^{n-1}\right)
\end{equation}

and then use the infinite sum of a geometric series to find $S$ more directly.  (N.B.  I know that $|a|<1$).

Comment: Are $S$ and $X$ PDFs or RVs? Your comment about convolution is quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks @gunes - I have edited to (hopefully) clarify my question.

Comment: 1. Your title says you are summing pdfs (note that the sum of two pdfs is not a pdf!), but your body text seems to be doing things with random variables instead. They should be consistent (the pdf of a sum is not a sum of pdfs). 2. Are all the instances of $X$ in the first equation meant to be identical, or do you actually mean each term to be a different random variate, like $S= aX_1+a^2X_2+a^3X_3+...$ (with the $X_i$ presumably independent). If they're really all $X$ then you don't have independence, and so won't use convolution.

Comment: @Glen_b - they are independent realisations of a random variable, drawn from a known distribution. I've edited the post to make this clearer....

Comment: About g(X) and g(S), again, no, you can't.

Comment: You wrote "infinite" without showing that clearly in the formula.  If you really mean infinite, as in $$S_i=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a^{j+1}X_{i-j},$$ and if the $X_i$ are *iid,* then you can learn a great deal about the distribution of $S_i$ from the fact that $a(S_i+X_{i-1})=S_{i-1}$ and $S_i$ must have the same distribution: that gives you a formal solution for the distribution of the $S_i$ in terms of $a$ and the common distribution of the $X_i.$

Comment: @whuber - yes, I did mean that. Could you elaborate a little further please? This is related to my other recent question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484542/the-cumulative-sum-of-the-difference-between-dependent-gamma-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas for geometric series, i.e. $$S=Xa(1+a+\dots+a^{n-2})=X\frac{a-a^{n}}{1-a}$$

> I know that  is the convolution of all the terms on the right hand
> side

This is not true because the summands are dependent.

**Edit:**
Based on your correction, i.e. $S=aX_i+\dots +a^{n-1}X_{i-n+1}$, you cannot use geometric series as above, but you can use convolutions.

Comment: Thanks @gunes - but I don't quite understand.  The X's are independent - what was the issue?

Comment: All of the $X$'s in the expression are the same RV. If you want to represent different RVs with the same distribution, you can call them as $X_i$ and then you can use convolution but not geometric series.